# SQL Server 2008R2 instance PORT changed to Default 1433 but not getting connect

Tags: sql-server, database-administration

For some requirement I have changed to SQL Server instance port from 1433 to 1434, which was success and after changing the port I was able to connect the SQL using the 1434 port.

After sine days, I have to rollback the port again to 1433. Post this 1433 port change, Now I am not able to connect the SQL server. But I am able to connect it locally using named pipe.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys!

This has been solved by rebooting the DB Server.